# Google API usage rate confusion

Tags: ios, google-api, pagespeed, rate, google-pagespeed

I want to use the Page Speed APIs in my iOS app. For the usage allowance it says 25000/day, 1 request/second per user. If I'm using it from an iOS app where the app is making the request directly, as opposed to a webserver making the requests, does that mean I only get 25000/day from my total user base, or 25000/day for each user as long as I don't make more than 1 request per second?
Thanks!

Comment: You wil receive more answers if you will check which ones are correct.

Answer (score 1):

It means that you have 25000 requests/day limit for all userbase, i.e. for all your users summary (for your app id literally). And as additional condition, one user can send not more than 1 request per second.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought, but didn't know if it was different when running it on iOS.